# Error: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character for enumerated field

Tags: enums, h2

I've got an error

`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "SWEDISH_MARKET"; SQL statement:`

when I pass an enum as parameter to query

Entity has this enum as field.

Field has bellow annotations

```
@Column(name = "market", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Market type;
```

query:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT count(*) " + 
                "FROM Statements statements WHERE " +
                "market = :market",
            nativeQuery = true)
    long countStatements(@Param("licenseMarket") Market market);
```

Previously everything was parsed to String and casted in postgres `market = (cast :market as text)`

Invoking countStatements(Market.SWEDISH_MARKET) throws the exception

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the (SQL?) code that generates that error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name here you are, but the query doesn't show more information than original question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is enum was parsed automatically to the number, regardless column type is text.

Solutions are:

- invoke on enum method .name() and pass a param as String,
- use SpEL :#{#market?.name()},

Answer (score 2):

You have to use JPQL, then it parse enums automatia